# Javascript array.push in Promise.all returning undefined

Tags: javascript

I have a promise and I'm pushing a value to Promise.all but it's returning undefined.

Here's the code:

```js
var arr = [];
    
        
    var mypromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('mypromise');
        arr.push(mypromise);
    }); 
    
    
    Promise.all([arr]).then(values => {
     console.log(values);
    });
```

How can I fix this?

Comment: 1) don't use the Promise constructor here. `Promise.resolve("mypromise")` does it 2) why are you using `Promise.all` for one single promise? 3) I doubt that it logs undefined.

Comment: This is where you made mistake https://stackoverflow.com/a/51100288/9674579

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
var arr = [];
    
    
    var mypromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        resolve('mypromise');
    }); 
    
    arr.push(mypromise);
    
    
    Promise.all(arr).then(values => {
        console.log(values);
    });
```

Try this.

Your Implementation for Promises is not proper, refer this 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise

Also, you are making syntax mistakes like arr.push should be after

```
var mypromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('mypromise');
});
```

and Promise.all accepts an array and what you are doing is wrapping an array with another array.

Comment: Please add some meaningful explanation along with your code so that the original poster can better understand how your answer solves her/his problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
var arr = [];

var mypromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('mypromise');
    arr.push(mypromise);
}); 

Promise.all([arr]).then(values => {
    console.log(values);
});
```

I'll point out to you a mistake you made in your code...

```
var arr = []; // arr is currently an empty array
// when you create a variable mypromose, it is also currently undefined
var mypromise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    resolve('mypromise');
    // even till now mypromise is undefined
    // what you are doing is arr.push(undefined)
    arr.push(mypromise);
}); 
// after it is completed, mypromise is now defined...
```

Hence, `arr = [undefined]`